# Requiring line of code to select nature of payment from drop down list

Tags: html, excel, vba, web-scraping, automation

[image]

I complied the below mentiond code line, but it is not working. I'm not able to figure out how to select nature of payment , the nature of payment tab is marked between arrows in the attached image.

```
Sub TDS_Autofill()
Dim IE As Object
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
IE.Visible = True
IE.navigate "https://onlineservices.tin.egov-nsdl.com/etaxnew/tdsnontds.jsp"
Do While IE.Busy
Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
Loop

Set doc = IE.document

doc.parentWindow.execScript "sendRequest(281)", "JavaScript"

Do While IE.Busy
Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
Loop


If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Challan AutoFill").Range("m2").Value = "Company" 
Then
doc.getElementById("0020").Click
ElseIf ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Challan AutoFill").Range("m2").Value = "Non 
Company" Then
doc.getElementById("0021").Click
End If



If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Challan AutoFill").Range("o2").Value = "(200) 
TDS/TCS Payable by Taxpayer" Then
doc.getElementById("200").Click
ElseIf ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Challan AutoFill").Range("o2").Value = "(400) 
TDS/TCS Regular Assessment" Then
doc.getElementById("400").Click
End If

doc.getElementsByName("NaturePayment").Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Challan 
AutoFill").Range("q2").Value



End Sub
```

Comment: last line of my code is not working.

Comment: Do you get an error when it's not working? Or does it just not change?

Comment: I get the error as - Run-time error '438': Object doesn't support this property or method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `selectedIndex` on the `select` itself then specify index of option of interest in the list under that select. I

```
ie.document.querySelector("select.form-control").SelectedIndex = 2 '3 or 3 etc....
```

Or

Use `.Selected = True` on the option element itself e.g.

```
ie.document.querySelector("[value='193 - Interest on Securities']").Selected = True
```

Comment: This is working fine, but I have one more select.form-control in the given website by the name of Assessment Year, what should I do for this?

Answer (score 0):

the `getElementsByName` method returns an array of elements, even if there is only one element with that name. You have to use `getElementsByName("NaturePayment")(0).Value` instead.

Comment: It is not working, but I'm not getting any error now.

Comment: While inspecting elements this is the code which I get for Nature of Payment Tab 
 <select name="NaturePayment" class="form-control">
              
      
               <option selected="">Nature of Payment</option>
    
              
               <option value="193 - Interest on Securities">193 - Interest on Securities</option> 
              
               <option value="194 - Dividend">194 - Dividend</option> 
              
               <option value="195 - Other sums payable to a non-resident">195 - Other sums payable to a non-resident</option> 
              </select>